# How to convert string from a configuration file to a readable key?

Tags: c#

I have a configuration .xml file which contains the following keys:

```
<add key="key1" value="D1"/>
<add key="key2" value="D2"/>
<add key="key3" value="D3"/>
<add key="key4" value="D4"/>
<add key="key5" value="D5"/>
```

Now I need those keys to be used here, so I tried this but doesn't work:

```
string k1 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key1"];
string k2 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key2"];
string k3 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key3"];
string k4 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key4"];
string k5 = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["key5"];

Keys Key1 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), k1);
Keys Key2 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), k2);
Keys Key3 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), k3);
Keys Key4 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), k4);
Keys Key5 = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), k5);

switch (e.KeyCode)
 {
  case Keys.Key1:
   //something happens here
  break;
  case Keys.Key2:
   //something happens here
  break;
  case Keys.Key3:
   //something happens here
  break;
  case Keys.Key4:
   //something happens here
  break;
  case Keys.Key5:
   //something happens here
  break;
 }
```

This are the errors I get:

```
Error   1   'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'Key1'
Error   2   'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'Key2'
Error   3   'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'Key3'
Error   4   'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'Key4'
Error   5   'System.Windows.Forms.Keys' does not contain a definition for 'Key5'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @mclaassen 100% sure.

Comment: @dotnetstep http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use a switch statement in this case. There is no way to have case values who's value is initialized at runtime. A switch case requires a constant value and constants have to be compile time constant.

Use an `if`, `else if` etc. statement instead and just compare the string values from your config to the `KeyCode.ToString()` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Key1`, `Key2`, etc. are just variables, not members of the `Keys` enum.  Use them like variables, i.e.

```
switch (e.KeyCode)
 {
  case Key1:
   //something happens here
  break;
  case Key2:
   //something happens here
  break;
```

EDIT: As that code is not valid, a `switch` statement is not an option.  You'll have to use `if`...`else if`:

```
if (e.KeyCode == Key1)
{
    //something happens here
}
else if (e.KeyCode == Key2)
{
    //something happens here
}
```

Comment: This won't work anyway will it? Cases in switch need to be constants.

Comment: @jmcilhinney That is not the solution: `Error 1 A constant value is expected`

Comment: B*gger!  Too used to VB.NET `Select Case` statements.  That obviously means that you can't use a `switch` because you're not using constant values, so you'll need to use `if`...`else if` statements.